# testing ActionMailer deliveries against a remote host

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara, actionmailer

So I have a simple scenario where a newly registered user must be approved by an admin. Upon approval, they receive a mail notification. The test, however, fails at the last step. Here's the cuke:

```
@javascript
Scenario: approving users
  Given user exists with email: "user@site.com", approved: false
    And I am on the admin panel
  When I approve the user user@site.com
  Then user should exist with email: "user@site.com", approved: true
    And the page should have no "approve" items
    And an email should have been sent to "user@site.com" with the subject "user_mailer.notify_approved.subject"
```

The step definition (it's [here](http://pastie.org/6288724)) tries to look up the mail in ActionMailer deliveries and can't find it.

What makes the test fail is that in my test setup, I tell Capybara not to run a server instance but connect to a remote server (Thin with a self-signed cert). Here's the setup:

```
config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller
config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods

config.before(:suite) do
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
end

config.before(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.start
end

config.after(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
end

# have to run the test env server separately, e.g. with thin:
# thin start -p 5678 --ssl -e test
Capybara.configure do |c|
  c.run_server = false
  c.server_port = 5678
  c.app_host = "https://localhost:%d" % c.server_port
end
```

The delivery is missing apparently because the mail is sent from the remote test server, triggered by Capybara clicking an approve link:

```
When /^I approve the user (.*?)$/ do |email|
  page.find(:xpath, "//tr[descendant::a[text()='#{email}']]/td[@class='actions']//li[@class='approve']/a").click
end
```

So the question is if there is a way to somehow tell if the mail really got delivered in this scenario. One way I can think of is extend the step above to also update the corresponding user instance locally which would execute the same code locally, but that seems to smell. Not using SSL could be another w/a, but I should really run over https. Are there any other options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so for the lack of an answer, here's how I solved it:

```
When /^I approve the user (.*?)$/ do |email|
  page.find(:xpath, "//tr[descendant::a[text()='#{email}']]/td[@class='actions']//li[@class='approve']/a").click

  u = User.find_by_email(email)
  u.approved = true
  u.save
end
```

The three lines added ensure the mail notification callback is also triggered locally.